# Delphi - problem with consuming SOAP with x509 certificate authentication

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, webservice-client

We should use a SOAP web service that is written in c# with Delphi 10.4.2 OR 11.0

related WSDL file successfully imported and the Delphi related code is generated no problem.
the problem is we should use x509 certificate as authentication method but webservice is on HTTP not HTTPS

first we install certificate on local machine and use certificate in HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.ClientCertificate by its serial number and call a method with no success. server just close the connection with 0 length reply.

after that we receive a simple working code in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GeneralUtilityService.GeneralUtilityServiceSR;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;

namespace GeneralUtilityServiceProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GeneralUtilityService client = new GeneralUtilityService();

            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2("d:/test/test.cer");
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("d:/test/test.p12", "123456", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            var result = client.getLastStatusOfEmployees("username","password");
            var nn = result[0].lastStatusCheck;
            Console.WriteLine(nn);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

but i don't know its equivalent in Delphi to handle certificate like this

any helps would be appreciated

best regards

Comment: Please show your attempt in Delphi as that is what you are asking about.

Comment: No HTTP response status code?